# Async functions in meteor server

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, soap, node-soap

I'm using [vpulim:node-soap](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vpulim&oq=vpulim%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l3j69i60j69i59.8492j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to have a soap server running.

My meteor server startup contains this amongst various other code:

```
  authRequestOperation: function(args,cb,headers,req) {
      console.log(args);
      var authResponceObject = {};
      var futureAuthResponse = new Future();
      Fiber(function(){
        if(collectorUsers.findOne({username: args.username})){
          console.log("Found User");
          authResponceObject = {
            username: args.username,
            nonce: Random.id()
          };
          console.log("authResponceObject is: " + JSON.stringify(authResponceObject,null,4));
          console.log("futureAuthResponse returning...");
          futureAuthResponse.return(authResponceObject);
        }
        // console.log("futureAuthResponse waiting...");
        // return futureAuthResponse.wait();


      }).run();
      console.log("authResponceObject after fiber is: " + JSON.stringify(authResponceObject,null,4));
      return authResponceObject;
  },
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. I receive a user object from client.
2. I check if the user is present in the mongodb
3. If user is present, prepare response object
4. Respond to the client with the response object.

I have 1. working. However, the dute it being async call, the order of 2,3,4 is messed up.

Right now what's happening is:

1. receive client object
2. return response object (which is empty)
3. Check mongo
4. Prepare response object.

I'm not using Meteor.methods for the above. 
How do I make this work in the right manner? I've tried juggling around `wrapAsync` and `fiber/future` but hitting dead ends.

Comment: Why do you use `Fiber` in your code above? `.findOne` is already sync. Do you see error if not using `Fiber`?

Comment: Since i'm running the code outside of Meteor.methods, I need to wrap it in a Fiber. Or else I get an error saying that Meteor need to run with a fiber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [`Meteor.bindEnvironment`](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment) can solve your problem, try this code:

```
{
  // ...
  authRequestOperation: Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(args, cb, headers, req) {
    console.log(args);
    var authResponceObject = {};

    if (collectorUsers.findOne({username: args.username})) {
      console.log("Found User");
      authResponceObject = {
        username: args.username,
        nonce: Random.id()
      };
      console.log("authResponceObject is: " + JSON.stringify(authResponceObject, null, 4));
    }


    return authResponceObject;
  }),
  // ...
}
```